How to get highlight annotation corresponding to stamp annotation in Acrobat comparison report PDF?
The picture shows the comparison report PDF generated by reading Acrobat in XChange.The documents displayed side by side are the old document on theThe deletion mark on the right is added as a stamp annotation, and the deleted content on the left is marked as a highlight annotation. left and the new document on the right.Currently I'm looping through all the annotations for all pages in this PDF and I can only get the stamp annotations, whereas I'd like to get the highlighted annotations on the left, can anyone explain how to do this? Is the comparison report compliant with PDF specifications? Are there any special markers that cause a file to be recognized as a comparison report?

